# Specify JMockit ClassLoader

Tags: jmockit

I use JMockit in functional tests. I need to mock classes which are deployed on jetty server.
That **classes were loaded  with WebAppClassLoader**, so I **can't mock** them because **JMockit uses AppClassLoader**.

```
URLClassLoader
|
|-Launcher$AppClassLoader
|-WebAppClassLoader
```

***Questions:***

*How to make jetty-server classes visible to JMockit?*

*Is it possible to specify JMockit ClassLoader?*